# Question regarding advanced calculus textbooks

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I'd like to start off by mentioning that I'm gonna begin studying Computer Science at  the local polytechnic university. As I found out, the study of mathematics stops after two years. Recently I've become really interested in mathematics, especially in calculus and I don't wanna throw all my knowledge out the window just because my university doesn't put that much emphasis on pure mathematics.

So I've started a search for advanced calculus textbooks and my attention was mostly drawn by Woods' Advanced Calculus(1934),but, unfortunately, this textbook's way too expensive .

Does anyone have a suggestion on this particular matter ? Thanks !

Comment: By advanced calculus you mean stuff like vector calculus?

Comment: I like Apostol, vol i and ii. Edit: you can find used copies for these readily.

Comment: 500$ for the pack, wow.. that's a bit over the top

Comment: By advanced calculus I mean vector spaces, differential equations, multilinear functionalism, integration etc.

Comment: That's a rather mixed bag of topics. Integration at least is straightforward enough, look for any book on measure theory, for example Royden and Fitzpatrick.